# Non-blocking sock_recvmsg() - is it possible?

Tags: sockets, linux-kernel

I have the following function calling it out of a kernel thread in a kernel module:

```
static int ksocket_receive(struct socket* sock, struct sockaddr_in* addr, unsigned char* buf, int len)
{
    struct msghdr msg;
    mm_segment_t oldfs;
    int size = 0;

    if (sock->sk == NULL) return 0;

    msg.msg_flags = 0;
    msg.msg_name = addr;
    msg.msg_namelen  = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);
    msg.msg_control = NULL;
    msg.msg_controllen = 0;
    msg.msg_iocb = NULL;

    oldfs = get_fs();
    set_fs(KERNEL_DS);
    size = sock_recvmsg(sock,&msg,len,msg.msg_flags);
    set_fs(oldfs);

    return size;
}
```

It blocks inside in sock_recvmsg(). Is there a way to have non-blocking version of sock_recvmsg()?

Something similar to MSG_DONTWAIT and O_NONBLOCK flags for the equivalent in User Space - recvmsg()...

Comment: `Something similar to MSG_DONTWAIT and O_NONBLOCK flags` - You may use `MSG_DONTWAIT` for 'flags' (the last parameter to `sock_recvmsg()`). Also, as your receive buffer is in kernel space, you may use `kernel_recvmsg` function: it already wraps call to `sock_recvmsg()` with `set_fs()`.

Comment: Somehow my eye missed the flags there. Thanks a lot!